# Submit form in a new tab and redirect existing page to xyz.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
function reDir() {
   window.onbeforeunload = null;
   window.location = "http://www.google.com";
}
```

```html
<form target="_blank" onsubmit="reDir()" method="post">
        
   <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Email" class="ema" name=email                          onClick="this.value='';" class=inp value="" style=""><br><br>
                
   <input type="image" src="images/enter.png" alt="Enter" /><br>

</form>
```

The form submits in a new tab just fine but I also want the existing tab to redirect to google.com, how can I do that? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Appreciate the answers ..

Answer (score 0):

Try like below.

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';



// Sets the new location of the current window.
window.location = "http://www.google.com";

// Sets the new href (URL) for the current window.
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";

// Assigns a new URL to the current window.
window.location.assign("http://www.google.com");

// Replaces the location of the current window with the new one.
window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");

// Sets the location of the current window itself.
self.location = "http://www.google.com";

// Sets the location of the topmost window of the current window.
top.location = "http://www.google.com";
```

Comment: I tried this one too, didn't work, the form submits and works in the new tab just fine, but the original tab which had the form doesn't redirect at all.

Comment: Thank you, timeout function worked, not sure why it didn't work without it.

Comment: Because Browsing contexts ..  Refer this..  https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/browsers.html

Comment: Each browsing context has a specific origin, the origin of the active document, and a history that lists all the displayed documents in order. 1-to-1..

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` and `window.location.href` should do the trick.

```js
function reDir() {
  setTimeout(function () {
     window.onbeforeunload = null;
     window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
  }, 10);
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="reDir()" target="_blank" method="post">     
   <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Email" class="ema" name=email                          onClick="this.value='';" class=inp value="" style=""><br><br>      
   <input type="image" src="images/enter.png" alt="Enter" /><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Awesome, Phil, this worked! If you don't mind explaining, what was wrong in my approach?

Comment: Cool! ;)  I guess you have to use `setTimeout`, because of two events fired at the same time (open new tab and function call). `window.location` is an object so you have to set the right property. In this case its `href`. Mark this as right answer, if it solved your problem.